# The complete extension of a probability is not unique

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The context is as follows: a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B}, \mathbb{P})$ has a complete extension $(\Omega,\mathcal{B}_1, \mathbb{P}_1)$ if $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathbb{P}_1\rvert_\mathcal{B} = \mathbb{P}$. I know that such extension exists: if $\mathcal{N}$ is the set of $\mathbb{P}$-negligible sets, then $\mathcal{B}^\ast = \{B \cup N : B \in \mathcal{B}, N\in\mathcal{N}\}$ and $\mathbb{P}^\ast(B\cup N) = \mathbb{P}(B)$ is a complete extension (moreover, it is the minimal extension).

I need to prove that such extension may not be unique; that is, if $(\Omega,\mathcal{B}_2, \mathbb{P}_2)$ is another complete extension, then $\mathbb{P}_1$ and $\mathbb{P}_2$ may not agree on $\mathcal{B}_1\cap \mathcal{B}_2$. A hint provided says that it should suffice to suppose that $\Omega$ has a small number of points.

I first tried to set $\Omega = \{a,b,c\}$, $\mathcal{B} = \{\emptyset, \Omega, \{a\}, \{b,c\}\}$ and $\mathbb{P}(\{a\}) = 1$, $\mathbb{P}(\{b,c\}) = 0$, but the completion is $\mathcal{B}^\ast = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ (and since it is minimal, I "ran out" of $\sigma$-algebras).

Then I tried with $\Omega = \{a,b,c,d\}$, $\mathcal{B} = \{\emptyset, \Omega, \{a,b\}, \{c,d\}\}$ and $\mathbb{P}(\{a,b\}) = 0$, $\mathbb{P}(\{c,d\}) = 1$. Clearly this $\sigma$-algebra is not complete, since $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are $\mathbb{P}$-negligible, but not null. So, one complete extension could be the minimal one. But I don't see how can I build the other extension; in particular, I don't see how to construct a second probability measure to be an extension.

Any hint or help will be appreciated.

Comment: I need a related result. Can anyone point me toward a theorem that proves certain probability measures have multiple extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. I would focus on the "extension" aspect rather than the "completion" aspect.

For that, one trick would be to have a set $A$ with positive measure whose subsets are not measurable:

Pick one of those subsets $A^\prime \subseteq A$. Then two extensions could assign different measures to $A^\prime$. If those extensions are both complete, then they are incompatible complete extensions of the original measure.

In detail, take $\Omega = \{a,b,c\}$, $\mathcal{B} = \{\varnothing, \{a,b\}, c, \Omega\}$. Define $P(\{a,b\})=P(c) = \frac{1}{2}$.

One extension might define $P_1(a)=P_1(b)=\frac{1}{4}$, while another defines $P_2(a)=\frac{1}{8}$, $P_2(b) = \frac{3}{8}$. Incidentally, these extensions are both complete because they assign values to each point (singleton set) in $\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed, I should focus on the "extension" part.